# How to check if TYPE ATTRIBUTE already exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, attributes, plpgsql

I'm trying to add new attribute to my pg_type and I need to check if there is already type with attribute named 'parentvehicleid'.

If I'm adding a column to the table, I can check the column_name as in example:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'tvms_routes' AND column_name = 'parentdriverid') THEN                                                    
  ALTER TABLE tvms_routes ADD COLUMN parentdriverid integer;    
END IF;
```

And can I check if attribute is already in type?

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'tvms_dseoptitree_routes_type' AND *WHAT GOES HERE??* = 'parentvehicleid') THEN                                                     
  ALTER TYPE public.tvms_dseoptitree_routes_type ADD ATTRIBUTE parentvehicleid integer;     
END IF;
```

I can't drop type, objects depends on it. Whats the equivalent for table column_name to types attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A composite type has its corresponding table (maybe virtual). You can find its entry in [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) and the list of its attributes in [`pg_attribute:`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pg_type t
    JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = t.typrelid
    JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    WHERE t.typname = 'tvms_dseoptitree_routes_type' 
    AND a.attname = 'parentvehicleid'
    )
THEN
    ALTER TYPE tvms_dseoptitree_routes_type ADD ATTRIBUTE parentvehicleid integer;
END IF;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, just need to fix table aliases, but that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Ops, aliases. Corrected! Thx for the signal.